# How to deploy an application that uses enterprise library

Tags: enterprise-library-5

I have an application that uses unity and the logging application block. I recent checked-out the application from the repository after these assemblies were added and I got a few error. Eventually I installed enterprise library on my pc and it's now working. My question is do I have to install Enterprise Library on every pc that uses it? If so is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your project which references the Enterprise Library assemblies is referencing where the Enterprise Library is installed - probably the Program Files directory. Instead of referencing them there, you could add the Enterprise Library references [via Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/EnterpriseLibrary.Logging), then check the packages into your source control as part of the project. That way you have the project and its dependencies all in one place, and it shouldn't be necessary to install the Enterprise Library everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have no idea how I fixed it. I think that my problem was that I was using the dlls and the config exe's from the enterprise library labs. I should have installed ent lib 5 on my pc. I had the same problem in my ci server so I deleted my project from the repository and added it again as my local was working.

So in a nut shell. Install entlib 5 and don't use the dlls from the labs in your project. I don't need to install ent lib in my deployment all I need is to copy the dlls.